# How do I set the uploaded files folder for SWFUpload?

Tags: php, upload, file-upload, swfupload

I don't see in the documentation how to set the uploaded files folder with SWFUpload.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I'm using PHP 5 if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you do is call a PHP script, and that script handles the file uploading.

You can turn on debug, this will give you a pretty nice debug view of what is happening, and the output of the PHP file in question.

The flash doesn't handle the uploading because the flash is actually running on the client machine.

Here's an example of the config I use.

```
    flash_url : "js/swfupload/flash/swfupload.swf",
    upload_url: "ajax/flash_upload.php",
    post_params: {"PHPSESSID" : "<?php echo session_id(); ?>", "folder_id" : "<?php echo $_SESSION["folder_id"]; ?>"},
    file_size_limit : "100 MB",
    file_types : "*.*",
    file_types_description : "All Files",
    file_upload_limit : 100,
    file_queue_limit : 0,
    custom_settings : {
        progressTarget : "fsUploadProgress",
        cancelButtonId : "btnCancel"
    },
    debug: true,
```

Then flash_upload.php has something like this (just an example)

```
$location = "/var/www/html/example.com/files/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"], location .$_FILES["Filedata"]["name"]
```

Answer (score 2):

SWFUpload is given a URL to send the upload to, e.g. http://yourdomain.com/upload.php - it is this script which determines what will happen to the upload.

See the PHP Manual section on [Handling File Uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more information.

Comment: well I didn't succeed in building an uploading script by myself.
I'm using the samples/php/test.php and it said that the file could not be uploaded.