# multiple file upload in just single browse click without jquery

Tags: file-upload

how to create control in web application that allows multiple file selection in single button click similar to control opefiledialog in windows application

Answer (score 1):

You will need flash uploader, such as [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)

Also Check these questions:

[WebDev: What is the best way to do a multi-file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97198/webdev-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-multi-file-upload)

[Best way to upload multiple files from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582126/best-way-to-upload-multiple-files-from-a-browser)

[How do I set the uploaded files folder for SWFUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868722/how-do-i-set-the-uploaded-files-folder-for-swfupload)

Comment: i have to do it without flash. what is ActiveX Object ? Can't I use that ? if yes How to use it?

Comment: no way to select multi files with just the normal open file dialog, you will need a flash object, silverlight, java applet or activeX, but i didn't try with activeX before.

Comment: I would suggest keeping a classic file-by-file upload next to the plug-in based one, just to cover exceptions. In today's modern world everything including smartphones have browsers, but not all of them feature an up-to-date Flash.

Answer (score 1):

try [uploadify.com](http://uploadify.com/), they have it.

Comment: This is a nice one, but note its also a flash component but mixed with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces fileUpload component (see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf) is able to upload multiple files with a single click...but the selection of the files has to be done separately