# How do I use Google Chrome 11's Upload Folder feature in my own code?

Tags: html, google-chrome, multifile-uploader

Google Chrome 11 now supports uploading folders. Currently this feature is only implemented in Google Docs, and I have been unable to find any API documentation on how to use this in my code.

From what I can see, you click the Upload folder link in Google Docs, which displays the "Browse For Folder" dialog (a call to SHBrowseForFolder by the looks of it), you select a folder, and then the contents of that folder is uploaded to Google Docs.

As this feature requires upgrading Google Chrome to the latest version, or for other browsers running a Java Applet, I assume I can use this feature in my own websites?

I would love to have this feature in a Content Management System I maintain!

Comment: Is this part of the HTML5 specification that only Chrome has implemented? Or is it a Chrome-only figure?

Comment: @woran Seems to be Chrome-only.  At least I can't find anything relevant here: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: +1 for particular Chrome version :)

Comment: @woran Chrome only it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590058/does-html5-allow-drag-drop-upload-of-folders-or-a-folder-tree

Comment: It seems WebKit only but works in Chrome and Yandex Browser Alpha too.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You should be able to see a demo here: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/demos/upload_directory/index.html

Basically it works by setting up an attribute "webkitdirectory" on a file input element.

```
<input type="file" id="file_input" webkitdirectory="" directory="">
```

Then when the user has selected a folder, it itterates across the "e.target.files" object to get a list of files included in the selection (this enables you to have access to those files from the clientside).

Drag and drop is similar, when you listen to the "ondrop" event on a "draggable" element, if a a directory or selection of files is dropped on to the element, the "files" property on the event will be a list of files contained in the operation.

Comment: Paul's exactly right.  As a side note, you'll need to add an empty `mozdirectory` attribute as well if you'd like the functionality in Firefox.

Comment: Does any documentation on this feature exist? Blog post mentioning it? Can't find anything on MDN/caniuse.com etc. What happens if you POST submit it, are all files uploaded and folders ignored?

Comment: This is awesome!  Does anyone else have any resources that would be of assistance?

Comment: I don't think Mike West is right. "mozdirectory" or "directory" doesn't seem to be supported by Firefox.

Comment: is there anyway to get Firefox to support this?

Comment: should the name attribute be important here it should be something like `name="files[]"` to create an array of the files unless it's something silly I am overthinking.

Comment: is there any similar way to upload folder on server through IE?

Comment: There is nothing like this in IE and Firefox currently. To check simply go to Dropbox and see if it's implemented there, if not, it likely means the feature is unavailable.

Comment: IE (Edge) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt574730(v=vs.85).aspx, FF - unclear for any specific attribute (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=782233), but can do drag-n-drop for folders - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423163/html5-drag-and-drop-folder-detection-in-firefox-is-it-even-possible/33431704#33431704

Comment: try "multiple" attribute for firefox

Comment: Does this preserve the folder structure?

Comment: It does not preserve the folder structure, this uploads all the files recursively. How to preserve the directory structure?

Comment: The link is broken!