# How can I select a folder in a Django form?

Tags: django, forms

Is there a simple way to allow the user to select a folder from a Django form? I want to use the same widget as for a FileField, but only allow the user to select a folder so I can process all the files in that folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826286/how-do-i-use-google-chrome-11s-upload-folder-feature-in-my-own-code Casual HTML forms enable uploading only files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible, you will never receive a directory name back from the type="file" input button

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you can use built in `FilePathField` with `allow_files=False, allow_folders=True`

[FilePathField, Django's model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#filepathfield)