# HTML/PHP Allow input file to allow upload of directorys

Tags: php, html, file-io

Hi I have made a php based file uploader to make my website more like a ftp server, but people can't upload folder or apps etc. because instead when they click open at the bottom left it just opens the app as a folder(Similar to o mac "Show Package Contents" and doesn't allow the upload of the actual app. Is there a work around for this?

```
<label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file" class="button"> <br />
<button class="button">Upload File</button>
<hr />
<?php
    $count = 0;
    if ($handle = opendir('files')) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != ".DS_Store") {
                $count++;
                print("<a href=\"files/".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Comment: use flash, java or silverlight, that's the only way to go around it

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tag input[type=file] is not really ment for uploading more than a single file. HTML5 however have an option to select multiple files in the same input. This may solve the problem for all users with modern browser, but the server will never receive information about sub folders or folder strukture, only the files with size and name as meta-data.

```
<label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file" class="button" multiple="multiple"> <br />
<button class="button">Upload File</button>
```

Chrome now has a new feature for uploading directories, if all users are using Chrome/Webkit you could use:

```
<input type="file" id="file_input" webkitdirectory="" directory="">
```

Ref:
[How do I use Google Chrome 11's Upload Folder feature in my own code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826286/how-do-i-use-google-chrome-11s-upload-folder-feature-in-my-own-code)