# Upload Folder in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Is it possible that i select a folder and then upload that folder to the server with all contained file and folder?
I don't want to zip my folder.
I use asp.net and .net 4.5.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826286/how-do-i-use-google-chrome-11s-upload-folder-feature-in-my-own-code for options - Chrome, Edge, Firefox support that,  IE does not, Safari likely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use html5 to upload folders, I found a solution here: http://sapphion.com/2011/11/html5-folder-upload-with-webkitdirectory/