# Choose Directory/Folder to save to?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an online application and I want my clients to save their files to a particular folder of their own choosing, could be documents, desktop or a newly created folder. The file attribute in html does not help. Is there a choose directory dialog functionality in HTML or JavaScript, or PHP.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: mmm, can't think of anything that would give you access to the file system. So I don't think you can set a default path to save things locally for the user, they'll go to their respective 'downloads' folder unless the user him/her self changes the folder.

Comment: Save what files, exactly? How the user download those files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826286/how-do-i-use-google-chrome-11s-upload-folder-feature-in-my-own-code/5849341#5849341

Answer (score 0):

In HTML and JavaScript, this feature isn't available as it causes security problems.

The user would have to manually set the file location which can be toggled in certain browsers like Chrome and Mozilla like [Shilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049127/shilly) said in the comments.

Comment: Sometimes when you are installing a software on a windows or linux machine, sometimes you are told to choose a directory where you want to install the software. How can I get that dialog box.

Comment: The user would need to enable this in the browser and it cannot be forced to be done from my knowledge